# Property '<>' does not exist on type 'Component' Angular 12

Tags: angular, ngfor, async-pipe

I am passing an object 'customer$' through to my html file using an observable and async pipe. The object contains an array of addresses which I would like to use to create a list using *ngFor; however, I am getting the error `Property 'address' does not exist on type 'CustomersComponent'.` Is it because I am referencing the customer set in the parent div?

here are my component.ts and html files, the line in the htmle file `<p>{{ address.addressOne }}</p>` is the one resulting in the error

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Customer } from '../shared/models/customer.model'

import { CustomersService } from './customers.service';
import { Address } from '../shared/models/address.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.scss']
})

export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
  customer$!: Observable<Customer | undefined>;

  constructor(
    private customerService: CustomersService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id

    this.customer$ = this.customerService.getCustomer(id);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="customer$ | async as customer">
    <div class="customer-header">
        <h1>{{ customer['people'][0].firstName }} {{ customer['people'][0].lastName }}</h1>
        <p> {{ customer['people'][0].email }}</p>
        <p> {{ customer['people'][0].phoneNumber }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interested-addresses" *ngIf="customer['interestedAddress']">
        <ng-container *ngFor="address of customer['interestedAddress']">
            <p>{{ address.addressOne }}</p>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my model for the customer -

```js
import {Address} from './address.model'
import {Person} from './person.model'
import {Note} from './notes.model'

export class Customer {
    public id: string;
    public people: Person[];
    public interestedAddress: Address[];
    public notes: Note[];
    public underContract: boolean;


    constructor (id: string, people: Person[], interestedAddress: Address[], notes: Note[], underContract: boolean) {
        this.id = id;
        this.people = people;
        this.interestedAddress = interestedAddress;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.underContract = underContract;
    }
}
```

And here is the model for the address -

```js
export class Address {
    public addressOne: string;
    public addressTwo?: string;
    public city: string;
    public stateCode: string;
    public zipCode: string;

    constructor (addressOne: string, city: string, stateCode: string, zipCode: string, addressTwo?: string) {
        this.addressOne = addressOne;
        this.city = city;
        this.stateCode = stateCode,
        this.zipCode = zipCode,
        this.addressTwo = addressTwo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small syntax error.

It should be `*ngFor="let address of customer['interestedAddress']"` (forgot let keyword) assuming you made no further mistakes.

This since the local loop variable doesn't exist Angular searches for `address` inside the component which doesn't exist leading to the specified error

Comment: In some ways, relieved it was something obvious, thank you!

Comment: No problem, we've all been there :)

Comment: If this solved the issue at hand, please consider accepting this post as the answer to your question. Thank you